# MC34063A: Problem with obtaining step-up performance

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, circuit-design, boost

I am working with a MC34063A voltage regulator in order to prototype step-up power management solution, with control logic to switch between three different output values. I encountered some issues while trying to assemble the circuit exactly accordingly to my needs - the output oscillated around 80-110 mA depending on the input setting. I decided to go back to the datasheet and to try build the exemplary step-up configuration in order to better understand what might be the problem while creating my own one.

I built the circuit on a breadboard with the only differences to the datasheet  one (picture below) being: 180uH coil, no Rsc resistor (no current sense, pins 7 and 8 connected together). When the input is set on 12V, the output measured is 10.96V. When increasing the input, the output increases accordingly, always staying around one volt below the input value.

Any advices what may be the reason for this kind of performance instead of obtaining the expected v_out value of 28V?
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried inserting \$R_{SC}\$?

Comment: Solderless breadboard? The push in contact resistance can be 0.5 to 1 ohm.

Comment: Solderless breadboards cannot be used for switch-mode supply prototyping due to their contact resistance as Mattman states, and also capacitance between pin rows.  These two effects make a SMPS unstable at best.  A PCB has to be fabricated for SMPS prototyping.

Comment: @Andy aka - I tried inserting Rsc with value 0.33Ohm since I do not have 0.22Ohm - it did not change anything.
Yes, I am mounting it on a solderless breadboard.

Comment: Is there any sign of switching activity?

Comment: I haven't measured it with a oscilloscope yet. I did not see any signs though from the circuit observation while playing around with it and measuring the values with multimeter.
Also, the output in this configuration does not stay on the 10.96 all the time. Sometimes it also drops to some couple hundred milivolt value and does not get anywhere close even to the input...

Comment: With what load did you measure the output voltage? And what inductor type (datasheet) did you use?

Comment: @G36 - I did not apply any load yet to the circuit's output, just measured it with a multimeter. The inductor I used was: BOURNS - RLB0914-181KL.

Comment: Today I built this circuit with Rsc = 0.39R and 1K resistor as a load and I use 1nF as a Ct capacitor. And the output voltage shown by my multimeter was equal to 30V.

Comment: What kind of a coil have you used? Do you think the Rsc resistor can be affecting the IC's performance? I've found some info that it is possible to just connected it without the current sense function.